# angular-cli ng command not found even if it is installed while docker building an image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, angular-cli

I have tried to build an image for an app with angular-cli as its controller. In build time with `ng build --prod` command, the docker builder crash.

I have tried to implement angular-cli on global or local folder, but everytime `ng` command is called, build console says that it cant build on a folder that is not an angular-cli app.

The problem is that docker build process run `ng build` on the right folder. Here is my docker file.

Error message: `The command '/bin/sh -c ng build --prod' returned a non-zero code: 127`
Other error message: `/bin/sh: 1: ng: not found`

```
FROM node:6.9.1

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ADD ./ /opt/

RUN cd /opt/ && ls -l

### MYSQL
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
  && apt-get install -y mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# ORACLE
#INSTALL LIBAIO1 & UNZIP (NEEDED FOR STRONG-ORACLE)
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libaio1 \
  && apt-get install -y build-essential \
  && apt-get install -y unzip \
  && apt-get install -y curl

#ADD ORACLE INSTANT CLIENT
RUN mkdir -p opt/oracle
ADD ./oracle/linux/ .

RUN unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip -d /opt/oracle \
  && unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip -d /opt/oracle  \
  && mv /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1 /opt/oracle/instantclient \
  && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so \
  && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient/libocci.so

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
ENV OCI_HOME="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
ENV OCI_LIB_DIR="/opt/oracle/instantclient"
ENV OCI_INCLUDE_DIR="/opt/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include"

RUN echo '/opt/oracle/instantclient/' | tee -a /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle_instant_client.conf && ldconfig

EXPOSE 30009

### SQL SERVER
RUN npm install sql-cli -g
RUN npm install @angular/cli -g
RUN npm install typescript -g
RUN npm install typings -g
RUN npm cache clean && rm -rf ~/.npm
RUN cd /opt/ 
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN ls -l
RUN npm install --production --unsafe-perm
RUN npm cache clean
RUN cd /opt/ && ls -l
RUN ng build --prod

# PM2
RUN npm install pm2 -g


ENV NODE_ENV=production

# UP app
CMD cd /opt/ \
&& pm2-docker start dist/server/app.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current directory is set to WORKDIR in each Dockerfile layer so it discards whatever you `cd`. So change

```
RUN cd /opt/ && ls -l
RUN ng build --prod
```

To:

```
WORKDIR /opt/
RUN ng build --prod
```

Or:

```
RUN cd /opt/ && ng build --prod
```

Also, make sure that the npm directory is in your "PATH" variable.

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to Docker and started playing around with it last night and I came across the very same problem.

I did not use ng build ( i could not get it working at the time)
I added the following run command in my dockerfile:

```
RUN npm run-script build
```

This was recommended by the terminal and it did work and allow me to continue my steps to build. 
I don't think that this is best practice? Feedback would be greatly appreciated.